# Ruby where is etc module file and can it be customized?

Tags: ruby

Etc module is great, but if I used NIS or LDAP where passwd, group, and shadow are not from /etc/{passwd, group, shadow}, then Etc module is not going to help.

Is it possible to edit the Etc module path's /etc/{passwd,group,shadow}?

On my Linux box, I have gone into /usr/lib/ruby/1.8, there are modules but couldn't fine etc.rb or related modules.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can use

```
SomeClass.method(:foo).source_location
```

to find out where (on disk) a method is defined. I don't think this was available in ruby 1.8, but even it is the result is nil, because these methods are implemented in C. The ruby 1.9 implementation is [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/ext/etc/etc.c) for example. Somewhere in  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8 there should be an etc.so (on linux or etc.bundle on os x and so on)

This doesn't mean that you can't overwrite the method, but it does mean that you can't just edit the source as you would with a plain .rb file (you'd have to recompile the extension afterwards and move it to the correct location, which is system dependant)

Comment: Thank you for confirming.  I found etc.so in /usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/.  It's a binary file.